# useSelector can not be called inside a callback

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I'm very new with redux / toolkit.

I need fetch data using the redux hook `useSelector` in my react functional component but the data isn't quickly ready so it seems that `useSelector` will return an empty array at first , then when the data is ready , it will return the popuplated array of data.

At first , i thought useSelector could be asynchronous but it's not. Redux re-render my component each time the data i'm looking for gets its value changed and that's not suitable for my functional needs. In some cases i don't want my component to re-render (espcially when only just an atomic part of the data changes, that strangely re-render all my component as well).

What i tried first is to make my data as part of my component's state so i can decide when i want it to be updated, i made the call to `useSelector` inside `useState` as it accepts a callback

```
const [data, setData] = useState(()=> useSelector(...))
```

but i got the error :

> useSelector can not be called inside a callback

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use **useEffect**.

```js
const selectorData = useSelector(...);
const [data, setData] = useState(selectorData);

useEffect(() => {
  setData(selectorData)
}, [selectorData])
```

If you do it like that, component doesn't re-render every time, it will just re-render when your selector data came.

Comment: At first i didn't want to use the useEffect hook because i supposed it will be called after rendering (equivalent to componentDidUpdate lifecycle method) but i think you're right , i can use it by passing the selectorData on its array